# How to stash with a custom message

Tags: git

I can stash untracked files using

`git stash -u`

I can also stash tracked files with a custom message with

`git stash save "some description"`

I'm having trouble stashing untracked files *and* using a custom message. I thought it would be as simple as the following but they don't work

```
git stash -u save "some description"
git stash save "some description" -u
```

Searching around the internet the only thing that works for me is

`git stash push -u --message "some description"`

I stash quite a bit and I find this a little verbose -- is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: Make an alias with it. `git config --global alias.whatever 'stash push -u -m'` then `git whatever "stash message"`

Comment: So `git stash -um "some description"` doesn't work?

Comment: just tried `git stash -um "some description" and that didn't work for me. would have been perfect if it did...

Answer (score 1):

`git stash push -um "message"`

If that's still too long, use an alias as one comment suggested.

You can read about all the options for git stash here:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Here is the relevant push option

> push [-p|--patch] [-S|--staged] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-q|--quiet] [(-m|--message) ] [--pathspec-from-file= [--pathspec-file-nul]] [--] [<pathspec>...​]

Also note that the save option would have worked if written in the proper order
`git stash save -u "message"`.
However, the save option is technically deprecated (and only saves one character versus the push option anyway).

> save [-p|--patch] [-S|--staged] [-k|--[no-]keep-index]
> [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-q|--quiet] []
>
> ```
> This option is deprecated in favour of git stash push.
> ```